# CakePHP On Last step of ACL setup

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

I know there are several threads asking similar questions - but I havent found any real answers to solve this specific syntax error, I have followed the tutorial over and over again and still end up with these error - I know its looking for a missing node in relationship between the ACL and ACO - ugh, please help

```
Warning (512): DbAcl::check() - Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check.  Node references:
    Aro: Array
    (
        [User] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [username] => admin
                [group_id] => 1
                [created] => 2012-06-15 14:20:44
                [modified] => 2012-06-15 14:20:44
            )

    )

    Aco: controllers/Pages/display [CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/Acl/DbAcl.php, line 79]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your app can't find the aco record for the display action of the Pages controller. The quickest way to ensure you have all your aco's loaded into your db is use the [AclExtras Plugin](https://github.com/markstory/acl_extras/tree/2.0), this will scan through your controller files and add all actions to your aco table.